# Set roundedcorners and rounded-corners tags to be synonyms

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I don't have enough reputation to do this myself - can someone set (or suggest) that [roundedcorners](/questions/tagged/roundedcorners) and [rounded-corners](/questions/tagged/rounded-corners) be synonyms?

Comment: Not knowing about this subject, is that tag significant enough to be around anyway?

Comment: @Bart - I don't know about that. All I saw was two almost identical tags on one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better if we just manually retag [roundedcorners](/questions/tagged/roundedcorners) to [rounded-corners](/questions/tagged/rounded-corners)

Synonyms are for when we think that there is a high chance that a tag will be re created. In this case, I think that won't happen--here, someone just blindly created the tag withought noticing that the hyphened one existed--and some others saw it in the suggestions, ans used it. Once we burninate it, I doubt anyone will use it (once the tag deletes itself)

---

I came back after retagging to see that this post hadn't submitted itself. Oh well :/ Anyway, here you go:

[image]

Comment: Actually, we should probably delete [tag:roundedcorners]

Comment: @ink it will delete itself in a day if it stays empty.